# Service provider initiated SSO( login page hosted on service provider domain) and salesforce as IDP

Tags: single-sign-on

The use case we need to implement:
1. External application(as service provider) will host a login page
2. User clicks on the login button on login page
3. User logs in using Rest API(receive access token) and lands to application's home page
4. On application's home page, User clicks on link to SFDC VF page and should not be asked for login prompt at SFDC end.

Is it possible to implement above mentioned use case with Service provider initiated SSO( login page hosted on service provider domain) and salesforce as IDP ?

Comment: Can we get saml resposne from salesforce after identifying only using Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing terms so it's not clear if the external application supports SAML.

If the external app does support SAML, step 3 is not necessary and step 4 will just work after SAML response is processed by the service provider.

If the external app does not support SAML and you're making a call to retrieve an oAuth access token, then step 4 can be done using frontdoor.jsp: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193348&type=1